# How to always get React component's top-level DOM node?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm given `this.props.jsx`, which is either a React component or a DOM node.

I want to mount `React.cloneElement(this.props.jsx, ref: { 'myElement' });`, then access `this.refs.myElement`

The problem is that the ref is actually a `Connect` object, and if I export that object `{ withRef: true }` then call `getWrappedInstance()`, the result is still a React component, and not the React component's DOM node

How can I always get the top-level DOM node for a mounted React Component?

I'm currently pursuing `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`

---

The only solution I can even think of is to target a wrapper ref and access that ref's children, but hardcoding a magic number seems stupid.

Comment: Use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` is in most cases discouraged because it pierces the component abstraction. Maybe it would be worth explaining why you need to to this in the first place so that we can make sure, this is not the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @trixn I need to measure the size of the component on the DOM to determine whether or not it should dock to the header

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly thought `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myElement)` was deprecated, but it's still fully supported, and makes this process much easier...

Don't have to `getWrappedInstance()` or export `{ withRef: true }`

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.